# UITextField leftView

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Is it possible to set up a UITextField with a leftView so that if a user clicks into the UITextField the keyboard shows but if they click on an icon in the leftView another method is called (i.e., one that displays a UIPickerview)?

Answer (score 20):

Have you checked that the leftFieldViewMode is set to something other than never

```
[textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Answer (score 8):

Instantiate a button as u do normaly

```
 UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];

 [btn setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Instantiate a textfield as you do normally

```
 UITextField *txtfield1=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,300,30)];

[txtfield1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

[txtfield1 setPlaceholder:@" Enter"];
```

To set a view in left side(there is right view also available)

```
[txtfield1 setLeftView:btn];
```

if u want the view to show always then below code does it

```
[txtfield1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

if u want the view to show never then

```
[txtfield1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
```

if u want the view to show if the textfield is not edited then below

```
[txtfield1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];
```

if u want the view to show if the textfield is edited then

```
[txtfield1 setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

button click event and pop over

```
-(void)BtnClick
{
  //Usual pop over coding goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a UIButton for this task? From the documentation for the leftView property:

> If your overlay view does not overlap
>   any other sibling views, it receives
>   touch events like any other view. If
>   you specify a control for your view,
>   the control tracks and sends actions
>   as usual. If an overlay view overlaps
>   the clear button, however, the clear
>   button always takes precedence in
>   receiving events.

So create a UIButton instance, configure its appearance and actions as needed, then set it as the leftView property.

Comment: Actually this does not work.  Here's what I have:
 UIButton *detailButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
 [detailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textview-list-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.propertyField.leftView = detailButton;
 [detailButton release];

The code compiles and runs without any errors or warnings in the console, but the button is not displayed.  Have I misunderstood this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the button's frame. Unless you specify a frame, it won't know where and how to draw itself, so you won't see it. That's why you generally want to use initWithFrame instead of init for UIView subclasses, so you won't have to be troubled with setting it later.